# Element scrollWidth value different in IE/Chrome/Firefox

Tags: javascript, html

When element's children has no height (**height is `0`**), the scrollWidth value was different in browser.

We write a demo, see below [jsbin](https://output.jsbin.com/retovav)

```
<body>
  <div id="div1">
    <p>Paragraphs</p>
    <div style="width: 8800px"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="div2">
    <div style="width: 8800px"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

`div1` `scrollWidth` value

- ie11: 8800px
- ie edge: 8800px
- chrome60: document.body.clientWidth
- safari10: document.body.clientWidth
- firefox50: document.body.clientWidth

`div2` `scrollWidth` value

- ie11: document.body.clientWidth
- ie edge: document.body.clientWidth
- chrome60: document.body.clientWidth
- safari10: document.body.clientWidth
- firefox50: 8800px